# Silverlight 5 Tools For Visual Studio - troubles with install

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I have Visual Studio 2010.
I installed Visual Studio 2010 SP1.
When I'm trying to install Silverlight 5 Tools, I get error below:

> Setup has detected that Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 is not
>   installed, which is required to install the following product. Please
>   install Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 and then retry.  Visual
>   Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 is available at http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9764693.
>
> Setup has detected that Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 is not
>   installed, which is required to install the following product. Please
>   install Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 and then retry.  Visual
>   Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 is available at http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9764693.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the tools aren't properly detecting that SP1 has been installed.  I'd try the following steps to fix it

- Reboot the computer.  It's possible the SP1 install needs a final reboot to complete
- Repair the Visual Studio install
- Reinstall SP1.  If Silverlight thinks it's not installed perhaps it didn't complete properly and another round will fix it.

Sorry, these aren't great solutions but this is what I would be trying on my machine

Comment: Unfortunately I made all of this things before I posted here.

Comment: @ogrod87 that's really odd then. Do you have other versions of Silverlight installed?  I may try uninstalling them.

Comment: I repaired Visual Studio 2010. Then installed VS SP1 and Silverlight Tools 5. Now it's all right ;)